# Large quantity of profiles in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have the maven project with five separate modules each of them have pom.xml with duplicated profiles. Is there any options to move all profiles from pom to separate file?

Comment: Is the concern that there are lengthy profiles in pom.xml or that there is duplicate configuration in profiles?  If later, you could segregate duplicate configuration into common profiles that can be activated by default or using some conditional logic.  This way your profiles will only provide unique configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the profiles into the parent pom. They get inherited during the build:

```
parent pom (with all common profiles)
- module1
- module2
- module3
- module4
- module5
```

You need to reference the modules correctly

- from parent pom using the `<modules>` tag
- from each module reference the parent using the `<parent>` tag

Comment: Can you write a simple example with one profile in parent pom and how to use it, for one module?

Comment: All child modules inherit all profiles - that's what you wanted right? -> "all profiles from pom to separate file". You can't just choose to inherit one profile and not the other. Activating the profile is a different matter, you can run build in child module with -PmyProfileName parameter to activate the profile named myProfileName. But again - if you do it in a root directory the profile will be active for all modules.